# GitHub API: Update contents of a file with a diff?

Tags: github-api

According to http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ the GitHub API can be used to upload the full contents of a file. I'm planning to use the API in a project that will change dependency definitions, so basically changing single lines. If I can only upload a full file, I need extra logic to avoid race-conditions (current best idea is branching from the version I'm starting from, then merging).

Is there a way to upload a diff instead of the whole file?

I'd prefer to use the API instead of cloning the repositories and using Git proper (big repositories, other kinds of race conditions).

Comment: No way to upload a diff currently. Neat idea, though!

Comment: Tech support on stackoverflow? Nice! :)  (could you make that an answer so I can mark it as accepted, and this won't show up as an unanswered question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to upload a diff currently. It's on the feature request list, though. :)

Comment: Is this still true after 10 years? Was this feature implemented?